# Channel Entries - Structure / Categories / URLs

Tags: channel-entries, categories, structure, url, child-categories

I've spent so many hours trying to work this issue out. Aggravating. I have a channel "Baler", this channel has various categories and these categories have sub categories. eg:

Balers
 - Parent Category
   -  Sub Category
   -  Sub Category

I would like to display the content for each page based on the last segment of the url. In order to do this do I need to create a structure page for each category(even though when I create a category it is assigned a URL)

Right now my code looks like this:

---

```
{if freebie_2 != "" && freebie_3 == ""}

    {exp:channel:categories 
        channel="{freebie_1}"
        style="linear"
        category="{last_segment_category_id}"}

        {if {parent_id} != 0}
            <div class="Product1">
                <a href="{category_url_title}"><h2>{category_name}</h2>
                    <img src="{category_image}" alt="{category_name}" title="{category_name}" /></a>
            </div>
        {/if}

    {/exp:channel:categories}

{/if}

{if freebie_2 != "" && freebie_3 != ""}

    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="{freebie_1}" 
        category="{last_segment_category_id}" 
        paginate="bottom" limit="20" dynamic="no"}

        <div class="Product1">
            <a href="/{freebie_1}{freebie_2}/{page_uri}"><h2>{title}</h2>
                <img src="{baler_images}" alt="{title}" title="{title}" /></a>
        </div>

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/if}
```

The main issue is, that if I have to add in 500 categories and sub categories, do I need to create all of these as structure pages also? Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The point of using freebie is that you shouldn't need to add them as actual pages.